# How can i achieve an image clip rounded with css

Tags: css

I have this design that i need to replicate, i am using swiper to display the carousel, i have the full images, i need the corners to be rounded like this:

[image: curved images]

i tried creating an a div that is position absolute, but it covered the carousel and i couldn't swipe left and right.

how can i achieve a curve like this one in the image, the purple curve using tailwind or normal css.

thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps post the HTML and CSS that you tried so we may best assist you in fixing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clip-path` + `ellipse`.

the syntax of ellipse is:
[radius-x] [radius-y] at [position-x] [position-y]

if you use as `position-y` 0%, it will place the curve at the bottom:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: ellipse(100% 100% at 50% 0%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `border-radius` for this.

Basically you could add a class to the div and then tweak the radius as needed. For example:

```css
.curve {
  position: relative;
  background: #1b1464;
  height: 50px;
  transform: scaleY(-1); /* flip vertically */
}

.curve::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%; /* tweak this as needed */
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 100%; /* tweak 50% value */
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="curve"></div>
```

Comment: That is the completely wrong approach for the issue the OP is facing. This places a solid cover pseudo-element over the block. that will also hide the image. This is a task for clip-path.